# Error using FileReader with ionic within cordova plugins on production

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, filereader

Im facing issues when test in production server with cordova plugin build, in local host It doesnt show any error on console, but in production is not working this code.
Please help me.

The code Im using is this:

```js
getImageData(blob){
    return new Observable( observer => {
        const file = new File([blob], image.file_name + '.' +   blob.type.split('/')[1]);
        const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onloadend =  () => {
          observer.next(reader.result); // emit the base64 string result
       }

      observer.error(null);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file); // convert blob to base64
    });
}
```

Calling passing the blob received from http client request

```js
this.http.get(url, {responseType: "blob"}).subscribe(blob => {
    const dataStr = getImageData(blob);
    console.log(dataStr);
});
```

Console show me this error.
Error: exec proxy not found for :: File :: readAsDataURL

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some one else face this issue, I could resolved adding zone.run() { }
Im using angular and ionic with cordova plugins.

```js
checkIfExist(url, showWhitePicture=true){
        return new Observable( observer => {
            if (showWhitePicture)
                observer.next(this.whitePicture);
            this.zone.run(()=>{
                if (this.hashCheck(url)) //_ Check if image is already loaded
                    return observer.next(this.hashImages[url]);

                //_ If not is loaded, so request the image
                this.http.get(url, {responseType: "blob"}).subscribe(blob => {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend =  () => {
                        this.hashImages[url] = reader.result; //_ Save in hash array to serve leter
                        observer.next(reader.result); // emit the base64 string result
                    }

                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); // convert blob to base64
                }, error => {
                    let breakPicture = "assets/images/broken-picture-dark.svg" // for light
                    if ( this.appService.darkMode )
                    breakPicture =  "assets/images/broken-picture.svg" // for dark
                    observer.next(breakPicture);
                });
                return {unsubscribe() {  }};
            });
        });
    }
```